# Скрыть линк при загрузке страницы

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Начал изучать MVC 4. Для примера начал делать сайт на нескольких языках. На странице есть несколько линков с языками. При нажатии на один из них меняется культура, и подгружаются нужные соответствующие ресурсы. Теперь хочу скрывать линк с выбранным языком, а остальные линки, вместе с предыдущим скрытым линком, показывать.

Подскажите правильный подход к этой задаче.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хранить вы можете:

1. в сессии, тогда память сервера будет тратится пропорционально количеству пользователей и будет проблема синхронизации сессий на ферме.
2. в куки, тогда память не тратится.
3. во внешнем кеше. внутренний не будет работать с фермой.

Answer (score 0):

Храните настройки языка в сессии.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Поясните на чем основан ваш комментарий?
Если это вам лично нужно не прикрывайтесь целями улучшения комюнити ресурса...
Утверждение мое основано на простоте реализации, для начала думаю человеку будет не тяжело сделать функцию которая определит по данным от браузера где он находится, выставит дэфолтный язык этому пользователю, а если он его явно сменит запомнит. Я вобще не понял чего вы хотели? Исходники, код?

Comment: Цель проекта - создание свободно распростроняемой базы прикладных знаний. Как результат, на содержимое накладывается жесткие требования: все сообщения должны быть содержательны и качественно оформлены.